# Laravel whereIn not returning all

Tags: php, laravel

Happy Holidays!
I'm stuck! I dabble here and there but am not extremely proficient so some help would be appreciated.

I have an `incident` record in the MySQL database which contains the field `incident_uid`. This is a comma-separated string which contains user IDs. This is then exploded across the application to form an array to look up user names when multiple users are associated with the incident.

I also have a `scheme_vehicle_log` record which contains a `responders` column - again a comma-separated string of user IDs.

I am trying to run the following but it isn't functioning as intended.

```
$incident_responders = explode(',', $incident->incident_uid);

$schemevehicles = SchemeVehicleLog::whereIn('responders', $incident_responders)
      ->whereDate('signout_date', '<=', $incident->incident_date)
      ->where(function ($q) use ($incident) {
            $q->where('return_date', '>=', $incident->incident_date)
            ->orWhere('return_date', null);
       })
->get();
```

It only either returns some rows or none at all. A `dd($incident_responders)` confirms the array as intended.

```
array:2 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/IncidentController.php:63
  0 => "97"
  1 => "17"
]
```

However `dd($schemevehicles)` shows as empty.

If I replace `$incident_responders` within the `$schemevehicles` query with [97,17], I get the intended result.

Tried for the past hour and reckon this will be something very simple - what am I overlooking here?

Comment: I would explode the incident_responders and then double, triple check if the array isn't empty.
Then build the query step by step, so you can dd() all the little steps on its way.
The query builder has a function like `->toSql()` and another function like `->dd()`, try to debug all the steps.
Your query can return 0 results in 2 or 3 places (as I can count)

Comment: I would do `whereIn('responder_id', $incident_responders)` instead, it's seems you are using whereIn on a relationship not a field

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both.

I managed to find the problem.
dd($incident_responders) was returning the data as type string and not integer and therefore the query was failing ("97" and rather 97).
Adding an array_map helped.

Thanks.